# make distclean breaks with non Automake external libraries

Tags: autotools, automake

I have the following problem with Automake. My project uses Autoconf along with custom makefiles and makefile templates. I have partially converted the project to Autotools and I am now playing with some make target to make sure everything works as expected.

The project contains external dependencies that need to be built first. These are non-Automake (plain make) libraries that I am adding to the project through `SUBDIRS` in the main Makefile.am. With this I can successfully build external libraries and even install them in the right `prefix`.

The problem, however, is that for external non-Automake libraries configuring in a separate build directory won't create any corresponding directories and Makefile(s) for those. Thus, when I run `make distclean` inside the build directory this fails locating the directories for the libraries and aborts.

One possible solution to this problem could be to make `configure` create the missing directories in the build directory as well as add a dummy Makefile that defines the empty `distclean` target. However, this is extremely ugly and I would avoid it if possible. Is there any more established way of dealing with this sort of integration problems?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not following the connection between out-of-source building and `make distclean`.  I would be inclined to say, however, that if supporting out-of-source builds is important to you then configuring your copies of the external dependencies to support it is an essential component of that.

Comment: `make distclean` will look for the copies of the external libraries' directories to run `make distclean` on those recursively. If I build in-source these directories will be there because of the originals. In an out-of-source build these will be missing. Changing the external libraries is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: There seems little point to out-of-source building in the first place if you can only do it part way.  If your third-party libraries do not support it and you refuse to modify them then the only good solutions I see are to unbundle those libraries or to give up on out-of-source building.  I don't see any reason to spend effort to support hybrid in-source / out-of-source builds.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best I could come up with is to create a link to the external library inside the build directory at configure time using `AC_CONFIG_LINKS`. With this, `make distclean` will run the `distclean` of the external library and eventually delete the link in the build directory.